# Drawing custom font to screen

Tags: java, android, libgdx

So I'm creating a 2D game and currently following a tutorial for adding custom font to the screen.

What I did is shown in the code below. I only copied the part of code relevant to this topic.

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen, InputProcessor {
     private SpriteBatch batch = null;
        private OrthographicCamera mCamera = null;
        private BitmapFont scoreFont = null;
        private int score = 0;

    @Override
        public void show() {
            mCamera = new OrthographicCamera(1920, 1080);
            font_texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("font.png"));
            font_texture.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);
            scoreFont = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("font.fnt"), new TextureRegion(font_texture), false);

            batch = new SpriteBatch();


        }

        @Override
        public void render(float delta) {
            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            batch.setProjectionMatrix(mCamera.combined);


            batch.begin();
            this.scoreFont.draw(batch, "" + score, 100, 220);
            batch.end();
        }
```

The problem is, the text is not showing. Could this be outdated method or what?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What is the logcat showing?

Comment: No, it's just not showing it even if I change location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to draw fonts on your screen then you have many ways to do that:

**A.** Using `.fnt` format

1- [Hiero](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Hiero) you can run it from your Desktop project with `Right Click->Run As->Java Application` then choose `Hiero` then create any style you want on the font then save it as `.fnt`. This tool will save image automaticaly then move these files into your Android project into assets folder then call font with the following simple code:

```
BitmapFont bFont = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/___.fnt"); // initialization
bfont.draw(batch, "" + score, 100, 220); // in render
```

2- [Shobox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dxPf1M7YORU&feature=youtu.be) is a free Adobe Air based app for Windows and Mac OSX with game and ui related tools. Each tool uses a drag and drop - or clipbord interaction for a quick workflow.

3- [Glyph Designer](https://71squared.com/en/glyphdesigner) is a powerful bitmap font designer, redesigned specifically for OS X Yosemite to take advantage of the latest features. Create beautiful designs using highly configurable effects, definable backgrounds, custom images, editable glyph metrics and more. Make the most of your screen with smart zooming and full screen support. Target hundreds of devices on multiple platforms with support for over 15 frameworks out the box. Streamline localizations with GDCL.

4- [Glyphite](https://www.glyphite.com/) is a browser-based Bitmap font generator that can create detailed Bitmap fonts in seconds and export them in most major formats.

**B.** Using `.ttf` format

1- First you must insert the [FreeType](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gdx-freetype) lib in your project, then you can use the following simple code:

```
FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/___.ttf"));
FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontParameter();
parameter.size = 12;
BitmapFont font12 = generator.generateFont(parameter); // font size 12 pixels
generator.dispose(); // don't forget to dispose to avoid memory leaks!
```

---

The [scene2d](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d) is good lib and easy to handle Actors with cool hierarchy :

```
//initialization
LabelStyle style = LabelStyle(bFont, Color.BLUE);
Label label = new Label("", style);
stage.addActor(label);

//in render
stage.act();
stage.draw();
label.setText("" + score);
```

Comment: Thank you! I managed to get it working with my original code. The problem was in font that I downloaded from internet. When Hierio is used there are no errors and everything is showing properly!